Will Boost serialisation break if I rename the class name?
I am working on a project which has working serialization logic. I have renamed the class name using Visual Assist. Will this break the current logic? Do I need any versioning to handle this?
I tried looking into documentation but it doesn't have anything about this case.

Depends how you implemented your serializer. Are you using your class name to serialize the data? If it's just class Test { int i; } and ar & test.i;, then no.

@pptaszni by that you mean ar & make_nvp("my_variable", my_variable) "my_variable" part? No, I am not changing it.
Though I have introduced versioning in the serialization logic of subclasses. The superclass is just name change.

It depends.
It is only affecting serialization if you you typeinfo. That, in turn, is only required if you have polymorphic base classes (and serialize them as such): https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_84_0/libs/serialization/doc/tutorial.html#derivedclasses
You will recognize this by exported classes: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_84_0/libs/serialization/doc/special.html#export
In that case you should use the named export macros:

There needs to be some sort of identifier which can be used to select
the code to be invoked when the object is loaded. Standard C++ does
implement typeid() which can be used to return a unique string for the
class. This is not entirely satisfactory for our purposes for the
following reasons:
There is no guarantee that the string is the same across platforms. This would then fail to support portable archives.
In using code modules from various sources, classes may have to be wrapped in different namespaces in different programs.
There might be classes locally defined in different code modules that have the same name.
There might be classes with different names that we want to consider equivalent for purposes of serialization. 

So in the serialization library, this is addressed by invoking
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_KEY2(my_class, "my_class_external_identifier") in
the header file which declares the class. In a large majority of
applications, the class name works just fine for the external
identifier string so the following short cut is defined -
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_KEY(my_class).

